# java: logging proto objects in loop in synchronized block

Tags: java, synchronization, log4j, protocol-buffers

I have a `Map` that is written to in threads x and y, and read in thread z.

Thread x:

```
synchronized (map) {
    map.put(0, protoObjX); // protoObjX is a protocol buffer object
}
//...
synchronized (map) {
    map.remove(0);
}
```

Thread y:

```
synchronized (map) {
    map.put(1, protoObjY); // protoObjY is a protocol buffer object
}
//...
synchronized (map) {
    map.remove(1);
}
```

Thread z:

```
synchronized (map) {
    logger.info(map.values().size()); // prints 2
    for (ProtoObjType obj: map.values()) {
        logger.info(obj); // logger is a org.apache.log4j.Logger
    }
}
```

**Only protoObjX or protoObjY is printed. Never both.** Why is this happening?

If I do `logger.info(map.values());` instead of doing one for each, then it works. If use a POJO instead of proto obj, then it works.

Comment: What implementation of a map are you using?  It may be buggy.

Answer (score 0):

There is simply no reason why this should be misbehaving because of protobuf. I smell a classic race condition. Try this, *in a single thread*.

```
map.put(0, protoObjX); // protoObjX is a protocol buffer object
map.put(1, protoObjY); // protoObjY is a protocol buffer object
for (ProtoObjType obj: map.values()) {
  logger.info(obj); // logger is a org.apache.log4j.Logger
}
```

If it works, which i'm 100% sure it will, you need to figure out what is the thread timing difference between the case which works and the one which doesn't. I suspect that you make testing POJOs locally on the spot while the protobuf objects are received from some networking layer.

Comment: I forgot to add the fact that both elements are there. The size of the map is two. See my edited question.

Comment: Try using `System.out.println` instead of log4j, and also try printing some specific string value from every ProtoObjType iterated, instead of depending on unspecified toString coercion.

Comment: Definitely works if I get fields but indeed something weird happens when using coerced tostring

Comment: Ok so you should make a new question "weird toString on Java protobuf object" because this has nothing to do with threads.